# How to generate a load report in postgresql when data is logged as sessions?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I do have a database that contains sessions: mainly something like:

```
user, date_first, date_last
john, 2015-01-01, 2015-08-23
john, 2015-07-02, 2016-09-01
mary, 2015-01-01, 2015-01-03
```

I so want to generate a report that tells me how many users where logged-in per day/week/month.

Is it possible to do this only via SQL in PostgreSQL?

Expected output for monthly report:

```
Month,   Users
2015-01,  25
2015-02,  50
2015-03,  12
```

Comment: what do `date_first` and `date_last` mean?

Comment: date_first is when the session started, and date_last when it did finish. This means that in this interval the user was active.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible by using series generating function [`generate_series(start, stop, step interval)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-srf.html). Example for months report:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(g.d, 'YYYY-MM') AS Month, COUNT(*) AS Users
FROM generate_series(
       (select date_trunc('month', MIN(date_first)) from sessions),
       (select MAX(date_last) from sessions), '1 month') AS g(d)
INNER JOIN sessions s
  ON (g.d, g.d + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day')
    OVERLAPS (s.date_first, s.date_last)
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
ORDER BY 1
```

This sample on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/482a7/10).

Similarly, you can write queries for days and weeks reports.